# Как с помощью цикла преобразовать временную метку в секунды и наоборот?

Tags: java, циклы, дата, время

```java
// [0][0] - день;
// [0][1] - час;
// [0][2] - минута;
// [0][3] - секунда.
for (int i = 0, b; i < test; i++) {
  b = (
    end[i][0] * 24 * 60 * 60 + 
    end[i][1] * 60 * 60 + 
    end[i][2] * 60 + 
    end[i][3]
  ) - (
    start[i][0] * 24 * 60 * 60 +
    start[i][1] * 60 * 60 +
    start[i][2] * 60 +
    start[i][3]
  );
  for (int j = 3; b != 0 && j >= 0; b /= 60) {
    answer[i][j] += b % 60;
    j--;
  }
}
```

Этот фрагмент кода. Он превращает дни, часы, минуты в секунды. А вот как обратно с секунд превратить в минуты, часы и дни?

Например `19 сентября 12:34:45` мне нужно превратить это всё в секунды, с этим проблем нет, а вот обратно превратить в дни не выходит. Каждый раз что-то не правильно.

Comment: А почему не хотите воспользоваться стандартными библиотечными функциями?

Comment: Потому что это упражнение на целочисленное деление. Типа работать с остатками и т.д.

Comment: _Каждый раз что-то не правильно_ - что именно? Не увидев код, сложно сказать, в чем проблема.

Comment: Не сходится ответ. Где-то что-то в этом цикле работает не правильно и конечный ответ когда переводится всё обратно в дни то день и час и сходится с ответом а минуты и скунды сходятся и так каждый раз что я не делал ....Могу скинуть полный код если надо ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли, что в сутках 24 часа, а не 60. И в последней итерации цикла нужно делить на 24, а не 60

```
int[] secToTime(int seconds) {
  int[] res = new int[4];
  int coefs = {24, 60, 60};
  for (int i = 3; i > 0; i++) {
    res[i] = seconds % coefs[i - 1];
    seconds /= coefs[i - 1];l
  }
  res[0] = seconds;
  return res;
}
```